# Laravel auth()->guard() returns null using vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a login form in vue.js. I just have to login user with vue.js and laravel. Once login user will redirect to a dashboard which is already developed with laravel only. I am trying to login but it is not working and `auth()->guard` returns **null** so that user redirected to the login page instead of the dashboard. When I use postman in that case it works well.

**Vue js**

```
this.$http.post('http://localhost/project/admin/vendors/validate_login',{phone_number : this.phone_number},{
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
})
.then((response) =>{
  if(response.data.status == 'success')
  {
    window.location = "http://localhost/project/admin/vendors/dashboard";
  }
})
```

**Laravel - validate login :**

```
public function validate_login(Request $request)
{
    $arr_rules      = array();
    $status         = false;

    $remember_me               = "";
    $arr_rules['phone_number'] = "required";
    $validator = validator::make($request->all(),$arr_rules);
    if($validator->fails()) 
    {
         return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg' => "Mobile number is empty"
         ]);
    }
    $obj_group_vendor  = $this->UsersModel
                         ->where('phone_number',$request->only('phone_number'))
                         ->first();
    if($obj_group_vendor) 
    {
        if($this->auth->attempt(['phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
                                 'role_id'      => 3]))
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'msg' => "You are successfully login to your account."
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg' => "Invalid login credential."
            ]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'msg' => "Invalid login credentials."
        ]);
    }
    return;
}
```

**Route:**

```
$web_vendor_path = config('app.project.vendor_panel_slug');
Route::group(array('prefix'    => $web_vendor_path,
                   'middleware'=> ['vendor_auth_check']), function ()
{
    $route_slug = 'vendor_';
    Route::post('validate_login', ['as'   => $route_slug.'validate', 
                                   'uses' => $module_controller.'validate_login']);
});

Route::group(array('prefix'    => $web_vendor_path,
                   'middleware'=>'auth_vendor'), function () 
use($web_vendor_path)
{
    $route_slug        = 'vendor_';
    $module_controller = "Vendor\DashboardController@";
    Route::get('/dashboard',['as'   => $route_slug.'index', 
                             'uses' => $module_controller.'index']);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not using laravel passport?

if you don't want  use laravel passport then use laravel default login method

Comment: @bhavinjr Actually I already did all the functionality of the dashboard. This is only change that I have to use vue js

Comment: A couple of things to check:  1.  Check if you have session enabled.  It is required with the default Laravel auth.  2.  Check that your user table has standard id field or you identify the $primaryKey field in your model for the user id.

Comment: can you please show your router ? also, could you check what the response is in then callback ?? thanks

Comment: @punk73 I have updated my question. It returns null.

Comment: what is value of $module_controller on validate_login routes ??

Comment: @punk73 It's path of controller file - $module_controller = "Vendor\AuthController@";

Comment: could you please explain to me where you set your session ?? i'm little bit confuse with your approach

Comment: @punk73 In auth_vendor middleware I have checked whether auth is set or not in not then redirect to login page.

Comment: @Dbb - Could you post your request? After you send the validate_login.

Comment: You need to send the csfr token when you do a POST request. Try to debug your request through the browser developer tools (you can see the request and the output)

Answer (score 2):

When doing a POST/PATCH/PUT/DELETE request from the browser, you need to include the CSRF token of your page.

```
this.$http.post('http://localhost/project/admin/vendors/validate_login',{phone_number : this.phone_number},{
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
  }
})
.then((response) =>{
  if(response.data.status == 'success')
  {
    window.location = "http://localhost/project/admin/vendors/dashboard";
  }
})
```

And be sure that you have the CSRF included as a meta tag in all your pages:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: I have disable this route to work withour csrf token. So no need to pass csrf token

Answer (score 2):

Just spitting out some ideas here:

- Try to set the `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` header for all POST requests.
- In addition, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header that should be in the **response** of the webserver. It is not a header you should be sending in your request from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have web middleware enabled on your route file in **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

Then check in **app/Http/Kernel.php** that             `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class`, is added and enabled in `$middlewareGroups['web']`

Comment: Yes both things are same as said by you but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an api guard, do this `auth()->guard('api')`.